# C# how to paint User Control with background Transparency

Tags: c#, wpf, background, user-controls, gdi+

I'd like to know how to paint User Control with background Transparency even if the user control is raised or moved at runtime.
my code is

```
private void UserControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.Clear(Color.White);
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;//可以反锯齿
    var rectBound = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width-1, Height-1);

    var b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204));
    var rect = new Rectangle(2, 2, Width - 4, Height - 4);
    if(!_isSelected)//FillRectangle
        g.FillEllipse(b, rectBound);
    else
        g.FillEllipse(b, rect);

    var pen = new Pen(Color.Yellow);
    pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDot;
    g.DrawLine(pen,10,10,100,10);

    pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 15, 100, 15);

    pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.DashDotDot;
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 20, 100, 20);

    pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot;
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 25, 100, 25);

    pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid;
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, 30, 100, 30);

    if (_isSelected)
    {
        pen = new Pen(Color.Black) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dot, Width = 1 };
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rectBound);
    }
}
```

and demo picture here [image]

there will be a lot of User Controls Created at runtime,some of them maybe overlapped,then it should be clear the user control's background.how to do that?

Comment: A UserControl is only transparent against its Parent.  That works fine, but *not* when you start overlapping them.  Just don't use a UserControl, use a plain class that implements painting.  Layers of paint, no problem with transparency, just like those yellow lines are perfectly transparent.

Comment: this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26878/Making-Transparent-Controls-No-Flickering